# swagger-request-validator openapi 3.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, validation, swagger, openapi, api-gateway

i am using swagger-request-validator-core library to validate request against open api 3.0. However, it gets fail for some of the requests with error:

```
Instance failed to match exactly one schema (matched 0 out of 3)
```

Is there any other library which can help in validating.

Comment: Can you post the request body of the problematic requests, and the corresponding OpenAPI schema definition? It could be that those requests do not, in fact, match their schema.

Comment: Hi @helen i may not be able to post the request and swagger due to certain reasons but it appears that this validation has failed for multiple users who are using Inheritance and Polymorphism including both oneOf & allOf.